# If I pass fragment object throw function is clean code

Tags: java, android, kotlin, clean-architecture

**For example:**

```
object ThisClassForNavigateToSomeFragment{
    internal fun navigateToFragment1(
        productId: Long, navigateId:Int, fragment:Fragment) {

        val bundle = Bundle()
        bundle.putLong("product_id", productId)
        fragment.findNavController().navigate(navigateId, bundle)
    }}

    internal fun navigateToFragment(
        productId: Long, navigateId:Int, fragment:Fragment) {

        val bundle = Bundle()
        bundle.putLong("product_id", productId)
        fragment.findNavController().navigate(navigateId, bundle)
    }}
```

Is this clean code, is this good if I pass fragment throw a function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you want to have different functions for navigation? You can simply add a method in BaseFragment or BaseActivity like the following. ( And extend this in your fragments or activity)

```
protected fun navigate(directions: NavDirections) {
  findNavController().navigate(directions)
}
```

This is simple, and you really don't need an object to do this simple task.

Since you pass NavDirection object, you can either pass one with or without extras.